# Are these correct extension of injective and surjective functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, terminology, definition

Recall the definition of injective and surjective functions:

> 1.a A function $f: X \to Y$, is injective if for all $a,b \in X$, if $a \neq b$, then $f(a) \neq f(b)$
>
> 1.b A function $f: X \to Y$, is injective if for all $a,b \in X$, if $f(a) = f(b)$, then $a = b$
>
> 2. A function $f: X \to Y$, is surjective if for all $y \in Y$, $\exists x \in X$, such that $f(x) =y$

I would like to extend them into sets, I don't know if these extensions are correct.

> 1.a A function $f: X \to Y$, is injective if for all $A, B \subseteq X$, if $A \cap B = \varnothing$, then $f(A) \cap f(B) = \varnothing$
>
> 1.b A function $f: X \to Y$, is injective if for all $A, B \subseteq X$, if $f(A) = f(B)$, then $A = B$
>
> 2. A function $f: X \to Y$, is surjective if for all $B \subseteq Y$, $\exists A \subseteq X$, such that $f(A) = B$

Can someone please check if these "set extensions" are correct?

Per Brian's suggestion I have edited 1.b

Comment: The first and third are fine. The second is not injectivity: it’s necessarily true of *any* function from $X$ to $Y$, by the definition of *function*.

Comment: There you go: yes, $f$ is injective if $f(x)=f(y)$ implies that $x=y$. And this does extend in the indicated fashion: if the set version of 1.b holds, then so does the point version, and vice versa.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks, your affirmation is better than a medal from the president

Comment: You’re welcome, and thank *you*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been answered in the comments.